# Let $A= \{(x,y) \mid \sin x \le y \le e^x \}$. Show that $A$ is closed on the plane.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $A= \{(x,y) \mid \sin x \le y \le e^x \}$. Show that $A$ is closed on the plane.

Let $f(x,y)=\sin x-y$ and $g(x,y) = e^x-y$. Now $$A = \{(x,y) \mid f(x,y) \le 0 \} \cup \{(x,y) \mid g(x,y) \ge 0 \} \\ =f^{-1}(-\infty, 0] \cup g^{-1}[0, \infty)$$

but how does this show that $A$ is closed? The union of half open intervals is clopen not closed right?

Comment: $A$ is the *intersection* of the two sets, not the union.

Comment: @MartinR Not sure I follow. How so?

Comment: Continuing Martin's comment: The two intervals $\left( -\infty, 0 \right]$ and $\left[ 0, \infty \right)$ are closed. And, $f, g$ are continuous. Hence, their inverse images are closed. Now you can use the fact that intersection of closed sets is closed and hence $A$ is closed.

Comment: $\sin x \le y \le e^x$ means “$\sin x \le y$ **and** $y \le e^x$”.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh How are $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, \infty)$ closed? Aren't they half open half closed?

Comment: @Simeon: Their complements are open ...

Comment: @Simeon Do you even know what a closed set is?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's a set containing all it's limit points. I'm not sure I follow how $(-\infty , 0]$ and $[0, \infty)$ contain all their limit points, but indeed their complements are open.

Comment: Which limit point of $[0,\infty)$ do you think that it does not belong to it?

Comment: Also, "clopen" is a set that is both open and closed, so a clopen set is indeed closed (and also open). In particular, since the real line is connected, only the whole line or the empty set are clopen

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the set $\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y) \le 0 \textbf{ and } g(x,y) \ge 0\}$ which equals $f^{-1}[(-\infty,0]] \cap g^{-1}[0,+\infty)]$, so an intersection, not a union. Both conditions need to hold, not just one of them. But intersections of closed sets are closed, so for the argument to be finished you just have to note  two things:

1. $f,g$ are both continuous.
2. $[(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,+\infty)$ are both closed in $\Bbb R$.

You seem to accept $f,g$ without problems but 2 is equally obvious: their complements $(0,+\infty), (-\infty,0)$ are open (by the definition of the topology on $\Bbb R$ if you give it the order topology), so the sets themselves are closed.